# How to set up word wrap for an stc.StyledTextCtrl() in wxPython

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, word-wrap

I was wondering about this, so I did quite a bit of google searches, and came up with the `SetWrapMode(self, mode)` function. However, it was never really detailed, and there was nothing that *really* said how to use it. I ended up figuring it out, so I thought I'd post a thread here and answer my own question for anyone else who is wondering how to make an `stc.StyledTextCtrl()` have word wrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so first you need to have your Styled Text Control already defined, of course. If you don't know how to do this, then go watch some tutorials on wxPython. I recommend a youtuber called sentdex http://youtube.com/sentdex, who has a complete series on wxPython, as well as Zach King, who has a 4 episode series on making a text editor. Anyways, my definition of my text control looks like this: `self.control = stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)`. Yours could look a little different, but the overall idea is the same.

```
self.control = stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
```

Many places will tell you that it will need to be `SetWrapMode(self, mode)`, but if you have `self.CONTROLNAME` at the beginning like I do, you will get an error if you also put self as an argument because `self.` at the beginning counts as the argument. However, if your control is defined with `self.CONTROLNAME` and you don't put the `self.CONTROLNAME` at the beginning of your `SetWordWrap()`function, you'll also get an error, so be careful with that. Mode just has to be 0 or 1-3. So for example, mine looks like this: `self.control.SetWrapMode(mode=1)`. Word wrap mode options:

> 0: None  |
>     1: Word Wrap  |
>     2: Character Wrap  |
>     3: White Space Wrap

My final definition and word wrap setup looks like this:

```
self.control = stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
self.control.SetWrapMode(mode=1)
```

And that's it! Hope this helped.

Thanks to @Chris Beaulieu for correcting me on an issue with the mode options.

Answer (score 0):

I see you answered your own question, and you are right in every way except for one small detail. There are actually several different wrap modes. The types and values corresponding to them are as follows:

- 0: None
- 1: Word Wrap
- 2: Character Wrap
- 3: White Space Wrap

So you cannot enter any value above 0 to get word wrap. In fact if you enter a value outside of the 0-3 you should just end up getting no wrap as the value shouldn't be recognized by Scintilla, which is what the stc library is.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps! I'll change my answer now. By the way, I'm not one of those assholes who downvotes for no good reason, but for things like that you might want to use comments... There are a lot of people who would downvote an answer like that because it's not a full answer. Anyways, thanks for the clarification! I just started with wxPython about a week ago, so I'm pretty new:)

Comment: Your welcome, and I agree about the comments. I wanted to make one, but unfortunately the site does not allow you to comment on other peoples  questions or topics unless you have 50 or more reputation. This means I could not comment on your topic until I had submitted an answer myself:P

Answer (score 0):

It would be more maintainable to use the constants `stc.WRAP_NONE`, `stc.WRAP_WORD`, `stc.WRAP_CHAR` and `stc.WRAP_WHITESPACE` instead of their numerical values.